# When does Firebase invalidate a session?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

In the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) it's stated that:

> But once you sign a user in using signInWithCustomToken(), they will
>   remain signed in into the device **until their session is invalidated** or
>   the user signs out.

So in which conditions does Firebase declare that a session is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general Firebase invalidates all sessions of a user when there are big changes to the account. For users signed in with custom token, the session becomes invalid when the user is deleted or disabled.

Comment: Do you have any sources about this?

Comment: See the exception description in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#getToken(boolean)